# Calling someone, "harsh"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-choice

I know that we can say someone is "harsh on someone," but I wonder if we can call someone harsh without specifying on whom.In dictionaries, I couldn't find definitions or examples of "harsh" in which it says it can be used that way. So I have the need to ask you guys. For example, is it fine to say sentences like the ones below:

> 1. He is a harsh person.

> 2. He is harsh.

> 3. You are being harsh.

**Contexts:**

***Sentence 1:*** I mean he is generally a mean person.

***Sentence 2:*** I  mean he is generally a mean person.

***Sentence 3:*** I mean he is being mean.

Comment: You can certainly use them all but whether they mean the same as you mean by mean is difficult to say.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks. What do you think they would mean?

Comment: You have it correct.  The first two are judgements on his overall personality, while the last one is a judgement on his current behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tom IS or IS BEING very naughty these days. How is correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/186346/tom-is-or-is-being-very-naughty-these-days-how-is-correct)

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, it doesn’t. My question is about the usage of “harsh” without “on someone.” That question doesn’t exactly have anything to do with mine.

Comment: I don't understand. The prepositional element "on someone" is nothing to do with *either* question. But so far as I can see, you are asking about the difference between *He **is** mean* (a permanent characteristic) and *He **is being** mean* (a time-limited action). And the significance of the different highlighted verb forms there is exactly the same regardless of whether we're talking about harshness, naughtiness, or meanness.